# Kinect configuration

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i have Kinect 1 and i install the package openni_launch.
when i run: `rosrun openni_launch openni.launch`, i receive :

```
No devices connected .... waiting for devices to be connected
```

LED green of kinect flashes
what can i do please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234993/kinect-configuration/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this

```
roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2016-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1